# Where is the best place to put the code of loading data from DB and assigning it to an application scope variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 application, I would like to load some data from database, and put the loaded data in a application scope variable. Where is the best place to put this code?

(I would like to load the data after Initializer file has been run, so please do not recommend me to put it under initializer.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of data you are using.
Otherwise following ways are possible

1. session(prefer)
2. cookie
3. file system

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationController in a method that is called by before_filter?

In the method use a nil guard. Not sure if this work but throwing it out there.